# Is Paypal payments pro gateway available for Drupal Commerce

Tags: 7, commerce

I am aware of the module [Commerce PayPal](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal)
 but according to the description it only handles redirects to Paypal and not the Payments Pro gateway which allows site users to stay on the site and have their payment processed by Paypal.

What I'm wondering is - has anybody crossed this bridge?
It seems like a pretty major issue for any commerce system worth its salt to address.

I'm also curious if there is any code out there that folks are using which may not be ready for contrib, but could be plugged into the back end of a site.

Are there any development efforts in this direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Commerce Paypal's issue queue, there is a patch that is a start on WPP. http://drupal.org/node/1155768